# Imprimir dados da Tabela MySQL em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
//iniciando a conexão com o banco de dados 
include_once("conectar.php");
if (!$strcon) {
 die('Não foi possível conectar ao Banco de Dados');
}

$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM cadastro");
$exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo "<table>"; 
echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";
?>
```

Já tentei criar a estrutura de várias formas.
Os resultados exibidos em HTML para mim são:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Sites\Projetos\Agenda\consulta.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Sites\Projetos\Agenda\consulta.php on line 19
>   Nome:

Minha linha 18:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM cadastro");
```

Minha Linha 19:

```
$exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

Já modifiquei os parâmetros de várias formas, mas não encontro o problema exato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você só tá passando um parâmetro para a função mysqli_query() que é a consulta em si. Sendo o correto passar uma variável de conexão seguida pela consulta:

```
$conexao= mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM cadastro");
```

Provavelmente essa variável de conexão já deve estar sendo construída no seu arquivo "conectar.php" sendo a `$strcon`, que você no começo do script pra validar a conexão, só sendo necessária passar ela como primeiro parâmetro na função, ficando assim:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT * FROM cadastro");
```

Retirado da documentação oficial [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Provavelmente, ele só deve pegar essa variável que está sendo construída nesse "conectar.php" e passar como primeiro parâmetro.

Comment: Adicionei sua observação na resposta @LeoCaracciolo.

Comment: Agora ficou show!

Comment: a variável de conexão é `$strcon`